# OSMNX Shortest path Nodes - Get node traveled time

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I wanted to get the travel time between nodes in shortest path route using Osmnx. Is there a way to get the travel time between the nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
import pandas as pd

pla__version__Piedmont, CA, USA
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive')

orig = list(G)[0]
dest = list(G)[-1]
route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest)
#fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G, route, route_linewidth=6, node_size=0, bgcolor='k')


for i, val in enumerate(route):
    print(i, val, G.nodes[val]['x'], G.nodes[val]['y'])
```

I want to store the nodes, the latitude and longitude which is implemented in the above loop, but is there a way to store also the travel time between the two nodes and/or distance between the two nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OSM's data on speeds and travel times tend to be spotty. Use OSMnx's [speed module](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.speed) to impute missing edge speeds and calculate free-flow travel times.

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

place = 'Piedmont, CA, USA'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive')

# impute missing edge speeds and add travel times
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)

# calculate route minimizing some weight
orig, dest = list(G)[0], list(G)[-1]
route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight='travel_time')

# OPTION 1: see the travel time for the whole route
travel_time = nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig, dest, weight='travel_time')
print(round(travel_time))

# OPTION 2: loop through the edges in your route
# and print the length and travel time of each edge
for u, v in zip(route[:-1], route[1:]):
    length = round(G.edges[(u, v, 0)]['length'])
    travel_time = round(G.edges[(u, v, 0)]['travel_time'])
    print(u, v, length, travel_time, sep='\t')

# OPTION 3: use get_route_edge_attributes
cols = ['osmid', 'length', 'travel_time']
attrs = ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, route)
print(pd.DataFrame(attrs)[cols])
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @gboeing This needs to be updated? I don't see the nx.shortest_path_length method in version 1.1.1. Is the correct approach now to get the shortest past nodes using the nx.distance.shortest_path method and then sum distance between nodes using sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, nodes, "travel_time"))?